# Animate effect on font-awesome icon during HTML audio onplay() event

Tags: javascript, audio

I have an HTML `<audio>` tag set up like this:

```
<span class="sound">
   <audio id="yourAudio" preload="none" onplay="playing();" onended="stopped();">
      <source src="bootstrap/pronunciations/jjugar01sp.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
   <a href="javascript:;" id="audioControl" onclick="playclip();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Hear it spoken">
      <i class="fa fa-2x fa-volume-down pronounce"></i>
   </a>
</span>
```

There are 3 JS functions to make this work.

**1. playclip():** This function plays the mp3 file when the icon is clicked.

```
function playclipwotd(){
    var wotdAudio = document.getElementById('wotdAudio');
    wotdAudio.play();
    return false;
}
```

**2. playing():** This function changes the icon while the file is playing.

```
function playing(){
    var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("pronounce")[0];
    icon.className = "fa fa-2x fa-volume-up pronounce";
}
```

**3. stopped():** This function changes the icon back to the original one once the file is done playing.

```
function stopped(){
    var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("pronounce")[0];
    icon.className = "fa fa-2x fa-volume-down pronounce";
}
```

This is great and works as expected. However, I am trying to get more adventurous with the **playing()** function here, if possible. Currently the icon comes up as `fa-volume-down`, changes to `fa-volume-up` during play and goes back to `fa-volume-down` when the play is over. This is to give the user a visual cue that the audio is on. What I want to add is, if possible, a way to animate the speaker icon during play to give an impression of something playing on. For example, would it be possible to somehow cycle the icon between `fa-volume-off`, `fa-volume-down`, and `fa-volume-up` classes, say 0.8 seconds each, in loop during the entire duration of play and then go back to `fa-volume-down` when the **onended()** triggers?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most useful for you is using gifs. There are many of them you can use for free or paid. So the only thing you must to do is the same you make with the function playing() but using for example this image:
http://thebontotrecords.webs.com/images_smile/Music_Animation.gif

Answer (score 0):

I just did some thing similar in an AngularJS app. 
I did it by nesting a few timeouts in an interval, and canceled the interval.
I started and stopped these events by adding .on listeners to the 'playing' and 'ended' events:

```
var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("pronounce")[0];
var myInterval;

var audioEl = document.querySelector('audio');

// during play
audioEl.on('playing', function(){
    // myInterval = $interval(function(){ // AngularJS way
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        icon.className = 'fa-volume-off'

        // $timeout(function(){ // AngularJS way
        setTimeout(function(){
            icon.className = 'fa-volume-down'
        },333);
        setTimeout(function(){ // $timeout
            icon.className = 'fa-volume-up'
        },667);
    });
});

// stop the interval on end
audioEl.on('ended', function(){
    // $interval.cancel(myInterval); // angularjs
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```